# What's the most stable memcache ruby gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached

What's the best ruby gem for memcached?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think defining "the best" might be a little subjective, but according to the most recent [Rails Guides - Caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html):

> Rails uses the bundled memcached-client(sp?) gem by default. This is currently the most popular cache store for production websites.

Answer (score 1):

### It looks like the new stable gem is [Dalli](https://github.com/mperham/dalli).

I was wondering the same thing and came across Dalli via a Rbates' [RailsCast episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/380-memcached-dalli).

In the author's own words:

> I decided to write Dalli after maintaining memcache-client for two
> years
> ...
> **it should be considered a replacement for the memcache-client gem.**

Hope that helps future viewers.

JP

Answer (score 0):

Use [dalli](https://github.com/mperham/dalli) gem, here are some of the reasons why dalli is better [memcached-client](https://github.com/mperham/memcache-client) gem

- Itisapproximately 20% faster than the memcache-client gem.
- Dalli has the ability to handle failover with recovery and adjustable timeouts.
- Dalli uses the newer memcached binary protocol.